# La consulta no me devuelve la suma de ingresos de cada producto

Tags: mysql, join

tengo la siguiente consulta :

```
SELECT *,fecha, ven_com, sum(cantidad) 
FROM `products`,`und` 
inner join ingresosegresos 
where date(fecha) BETWEEN '2021-03-01' AND '2021-03-31' 
and products.und_pro=und.id_und 
and products.id_producto=ingresosegresos.id_producto 
and ven_com=2 
ORDER BY `products`.`id_producto` DESC
```

necesito que me sume los ingresos que hubieron según la fecha y necesito que me sume pero por cada producto y LA CONSULTA ME devuelve la sumatoria total de todo lo que hay en esa columna, necesito que me devuelva la sumatoria pero por producto,

Comment: *necesito que me devuelva la sumatoria pero por producto* entonces ¿al momento que te devuelve?, por cierto te falta agrupar

Comment: me devuelve la sumatoria de todo lo que encuentra en la columna cantidad, y necesito que me devuelva la sumatoria de cantidad pero por producto

Comment: Hugo como te mencioné te falta agrupar

Comment: si gracias BetaM, ahorita acabo de probar lo que me dijiste y si me funciona a nivel de bd GRACIAS, pero cuando ya hago el query metiendo fecha con variables que captura desde la vista php me genera el reporte pero en la columna donde debe ir la suma de cantidad por cada producto me tira este error Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistemaOriginal\informeInventario.php on line 116

Comment: Eso ya es un error distinto y debería ser motivo de una nueva pregunta, si ya tienes la solución a esta pregunta entonces te invito a que la publiques, lo otro que mencionas no tiene que ver con el problema actual

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas añadir `GROUP BY` para que la suma sea de los productos:

```
SELECT *,fecha, ven_com, sum(cantidad) 
FROM `products`,`und` 
inner join ingresosegresos 
where date(fecha) BETWEEN '2021-03-01' AND '2021-03-31' 
and products.und_pro=und.id_und 
and products.id_producto=ingresosegresos.id_producto 
and ven_com=2 
GROUP BY `products`.`id_producto`
ORDER BY `products`.`id_producto` DESC
```